# Динамическое обновление Dataset через Tableadapter Visual C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, visual-studio, sql-server

Есть база данных `db.mdf`.

Есть DataSet, BindingSource, TableAdapter соединённые цепочкой друг к другу, созданные VisualStudio по умолчанию.

Я создаю строку с помощью `INSERT` в базу данных, потом мне надо сделать 
`TableAdapter.FILL(DataSet.Таблица,индекс_вставленной строки)`.

После выполнения `FILL` , `DataSet.Таблица` **пустая**.

Я пытался делать `DataSet.Clear()` перед `FILL`, непомогает.
Пытался делать `TableAdapter.Adapter.Update(DataSet.Таблица)`, непомогает
`DataSet.AcceptChanges()` не помогает.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было считать из базы данных `MSSQL(mdf file)` свежевставленную строку с помощью `DataSet`, `BindingSource`, `TableAdapter`?

Comment: попробуйте после компиляции запустить ваш .exe прямо из папки, минуя студию. Я как-то долго возился с похожей проблемой, что записи в БД не заносится. В итоге оказалось, что при каждом новом запуске из студии БД перезаписывалась на пустую =/

Comment: Не помогает. Та же проблема

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался. При компилировании визуалка копирует базу данных из папки с проектом в папку debug и в последующем  читает базу из debug. А я вставляю данные в файл, лежащий в корне.